# Getting error "Cant set headers after they are sent" when trying to upload image and user data to mongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am using Node, Express, Mongo and Angular to make simple app. I have a form where a user can insert data and upload an image. For image upload I use  [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). I am using [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/) to get the form data. Here is my API for the upload of the image to a server folder and to save and entry in the mongdb of the user data along with the filename.

```
router.route('/upload/image')
    .post(function(req, res){
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log(files);
        console.log(fields);
        var file = files.file[0];
        var contentType = file.headers['content-type'];
        var tmpPath = file.path;
        var extIndex = tmpPath.lastIndexOf('.');
        var extension = (extIndex < 0) ? '' : tmpPath.substr(extIndex);
        // uuid is for generating unique filenames.
        var fileName = uuid.v4() + extension;
        var destPath = './public/img/' + fileName;

        // Server side file type checker.
        if (contentType !== 'image/png' && contentType !== 'image/jpeg' && contentType !== 'image/jpg') {
            fs.unlink(tmpPath);
            return res.status(400).send('Unsupported file type.');
        }

        fs.rename(tmpPath, destPath, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send('Image is not saved:');
            }
            return res.json(destPath);
        });

        var user = new User();
        user.firstName = fields.firstName;
        user.lastName = fields.lastName;
        user.email = fields.email;
        user.numOfCups = fields.numOfCups;
        user.currentBalance = fields.currentBalance;
        user.totalNumOfCups = fields.numOfCups;
        user.totalMoneySpent = fields.currentBalance;
        user.photo = destPath;

        user.save(function(err, user){
            if(err){
                return res.send(500, err);
            }
            return res.json(user);
        });
    });
});
```

When i save the user data in the UI it copies the file into the server folder but it does not save data to mongodb and throw an error - **"Cant set headers after they are sent"**. I get it that it has to do with the `res.json` being called twice, but how do I solve this? Any pointers are deeply appreciated.

Comment: You do `res.json` twice. It should be done only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send multiples responses.

Fix:
Remove `return res.json(destPath);` and put all your code from creation of an user to saving the entity, in place of `return res.json(destPath);`